# Android Auto: How to return a large number of children on loadChildren() of MediaBrowserService?

Tags: android, android-auto, mediabrowserservice

I am currently trying to implement a `MediaBrowserService` to build a media app for Android Auto.
I followed the official Android Auto documentation (https://developer.android.com/training/cars/media#onLoadChildren) to implement the`onLoadChildren` function.

Following is a code snippet that I tried to show the content on the Android Auto screen:

```kotlin
override fun onLoadChildren(parentId: String, result: Result<MutableList<MediaBrowserCompat.MediaItem>>) {
  ...
  if (parentId == NODE_LIBRARY_ALBUMS) {
    val items = mutableListOf<MediaBrowserCompat.MediaItem>()

    val albumList = LibraryManager.getAlbumList()
    for (it in albumList) {
      val descriptionBuilder = MediaDescriptionCompat.Builder()
        .setTitle(it.albumName)
      items.add(MediaBrowserCompat.MediaItem(descriptionBuilder.build(), MediaBrowserCompat.MediaItem.FLAG_BROWSABLE))
    }

    result.sendResult(items)
  }
  ...
}
```

This works pretty well, when the number of items is small enough.
However, when the number of items is large (e.g., about 5,000 items), the following error appears:

```
E/JavaBinder: !!! FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION !!!  (parcel size = 1339384)
```

I found that several other media apps (e.g., Samsung Music) that support Android Auto can show a large number of items.
Is there any way to return a large number of items on the `onLoadChildren` function, or is there any other way to solve this issue?

Thanks!

Comment: HI. I faced with the same problem. Have you found any solution?

Comment: @DmitriyMiyai Oh you are on the same boat... I couldn't find any solution for this, so I started a bounty for this question.

Comment: I found why this happens - because of Android limits of sending the data in intents(1 Mb or around this). When you call `result.sendResult(items)` it sends the intent to show the data in AA. The solution, which I came to is just split the content to small parts. For example, if you have 5000 items, divide them with 50 parts and call it Part 1 - Part 50. Each part will contain 100 items. This is not ideal, but it was the best trick for me.

Comment: @DmitriyMiyai Yes, it is because of the size limit of the Android's bundles. But how did you combine those splits into a single list on the Android Auto screen? Or did you show each part separately on the screen?

Comment: Please see my example. Hope you'll find it useful for your case

Comment: Did you find an answer, @idearibosome? Going through this myself.

Answer (score -1):

Probably you have to split the large data into a small pieces. For example, you have a list of 5000 items. So inside you `MediaBrowserService` in `onLoadChildren` do something like this

```
 public fun onLoadChildren(parentId: String, result: Result<List<MediaBrowserCompat.MediaItem>>) {
       
    if (MEDIA_ID_ROOT == parentId || itemsList.size > 100) {
        fillMediaBrowsableResult(parentId, result);
    }
    else {
        fillMediaPlayableResult(parentId, result);
    }
}


//Split the large number of content to a parts
private fun fillMediaBrowsableResult(parentId: String, result: Result<List<MediaBrowserCompat.MediaItem>>) {

    // Detect count of parts
    val partsCount = itemsList.size / 100
    if(itemsList.size % 100 > 0){
        partsCount ++
    }
    val mediaItems = mutableListOf<MediaBrowserCompat.MediaItem>()
    //Create parts in a loop
    for(i in 0 until partsCount){
        
         val mediaDescription = MediaDescriptionCompat.Builder()
                .setMediaId(i) // This is your next parent in onLoadChildren when you click on it in AA
                .setTitle("Part ${i + 1}")
                .build();

        val mediaItem =. MediaBrowserCompat.MediaItem(mediaDescription, MediaBrowserCompat.MediaItem.FLAG_BROWSABLE)
        mediaItems.add(mediaItem)
    }
    result.sendResult(mediaItems)
}

private fun fillMediaPlayableResult(parentId: String, result: Result<List<MediaBrowserCompat.MediaItem>>){

    val intParent = parentId.toInt()
    val startPosition = intParent * 100 // where to start for this part
    val stopPosition = (intParent + 1) * 100 // where to finish for this part
    if(stopPosition > itemsList.size){
        stopPosition = itemsList.size 
    }
    
    val mediaItems = mutableListOf<MediaBrowserCompat.MediaItem>()
    for(i in startPosition..stopPosition){
        //Generate playable content for this part
        val item = itemsList[i]
        val mediaDescription = MediaDescriptionCompat.Builder()
                    .setMediaId(item.id)
                    .setTitle(item.albumTitle)
                    .build();
        val mediaItem =. MediaBrowserCompat.MediaItem(mediaDescription, MediaBrowserCompat.MediaItem.FLAG_PLAYABLE)
        mediaItems.add(mediaItem)
    }
    result.sendResult(mediaItems)
}
```

I didn't check this code, but I think the idea is clear.

Comment: This can be a workaround, but it shows the "Part 1", "Part 2", ... page first and the user has to look all parts menu to find a media item that the user wants to play. As I mentioned in the question, there are some Android Auto apps that supports showing more than 1000 items without any error.

Comment: So I think there should be a way to solve this issue without splitting data into several chunks...

Comment: This does not solve the problem as asked. User wants one scrolling list.

Answer (score -1):

If you look into Android SDK [document](https://developer.android.com/training/cars/media#onLoadChildren):

> Note: Android Auto and Android Automotive OS have strict limits on how
> many media items they can display in each level of the menu. These
> limits minimize distractions for drivers and help them operate your
> app with voice commands. ...

So, I think the best approach is to limit # of media items in UX design. For what you saw from the other apps working with lots of media items, they might used Jetpack [Media 2](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/media2) for [pagination](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/media2/session/MediaBrowser.html?hl=en#getChildren(java.lang.String,%20int,%20int,%20androidx.media2.session.MediaLibraryService.LibraryParams)).

Comment: The limit that Android is mentioning is max 4 tabs in navigation row.

Comment: This answer is irrelevant. The UI limit is not what is being encountered here, it's the limited size of the Android IPC buffer.